# Can all Django applications add items to a base template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm writing a webpage in Django and I have a application called "Website". This application defines some basic views and general layout of the whole site part of which is the navigation bar.

As I add applications responsible for different functionalities I would like to have them add links to that navigation bar. The links should appear not only when using a view from a certain application but in all others as well. The problem here is how to arrange this without the "Website" app knowing about all the other applications?

Answer (score 0):

All Django apps inside one project can be aware of each other. For example, if you had an app called `links`, you could use models and functions from `links` to create new content, then use that content in `Website`. You will need to import the information. For example, to use links from `links` in your `Website` views:

```
# Website.views
from links.models import Link

def myView(request):
    links = Link.objects.all()
    # do something with the links
    context = {'links': links}
    return render(request, 'webpage.html', context)
```

Please excuse my syntax and stuff, I haven't tested this or anything. I hope this explains what you mean. Feel free to ask more, I'll do my best to answer.